# Unable to figure out 2D arrays working in Python

Tags: python, arrays

```
n = int(input("Enter the number: "))
startRow = 0
endRow = n - 1
startColumn = 0
endColumn = n - 1
k = 1

matrix = [[0]*n]*n

i = startColumn
while(i <= endColumn):
    matrix[startRow][i] = k
    k = k + 1
    i += 1
matrix[0][1] = 6

print(matrix)
```

`output`

```
python print_patterns.py 
Enter the number: 5
[[1, 6, 3, 4, 5], [1, 6, 3, 4, 5], [1, 6, 3, 4, 5], [1, 6, 3, 4, 5], [1, 6, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Q1. I am unable to understand why second element in every array is 6?

Q2. In the first while loop I have assigned values only to first array elements but still it allocated all the rows with same data?

Comment: firstly change `matrix = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]` and read about `shallow copy and deep copy` from https://www.python-course.eu/python3_deep_copy.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Thank you Esi95 and Hampus Larsson

Answer (score 0):

In your method, Python doesn’t create 5 integer lists but creates only one integer list and all the indices of the list `matrix` point to the same int list.

[Using 2D lists the right way](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/)

Visit this link for more information.

Comment: Thanks KavG for answer